# How to call a sub component's method from a main component in React with Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to access a component as itself so that I could call its methods, but I haven't been successful at it.

I've a simple `TestComponent` which has a `print()` method in it. I want to call that `print()` method from `MainComponent`. So I did something like this:

```
class TestComponent extends React.Component<IProps, IState) {

   print() {
      console.log('From TestComponent');
   }

   render() {
      return <h1>Item</h1>;
   }
}

class MainComponent extends React.Component<IProps, IState) {

   private list:Array<TestComponent>;   //This is going to throw an error in Typescript. It expects type of JSX Element.

   render() {
      for(let i=0; i<5; i++) list.push(<TestComponent/>);   //<TestComponent> is recognised as a JSX element instead so this will throw an error
      list.forEach((component) => component.print());   //Since this is JSX Element, calling print() will throw unknown function print() error.
      return <h1>Main Component</h1>{list};
   }
}
```

It turns out that I cannot use `TestComponent` as the object type in Typescript. I have to set the type of my `list` array to be of `JSX.Element` for it to work. But if I do so, I cannot "up-cast" the type to call `TestComponent`'s `print()` method from `MainComponent`.

So, how can I call a sub component's method from a main component which contains the sub component?

And, in Typescript, how should I define my component's type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how react is supposed to be used.
The way you control child elements is by passing props to them and not by executing methods.

For example:

```
interface IProps {
    toPrint: boolean;
}

class TestComponent extends React.Component<IProps, IState) {
    print() {
        console.log('From TestComponent');
    }

    render() {
        if (this.props.toPrint) {
            this.print();
        }

        return <h1>Item</h1>;
    }
}

class MainComponent extends React.Component<IProps, IState) {
    render() {
        let kids: JSX.Element[] = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            list.push(<TestComponent toPrint={ true } />);
        }

        return <h1>Main Component</h1>{ list };
    }
}
```

If you need to save references to existing child elements then you need to use the [Refs to Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html) which has a few way of doing things, for example:

```
class MainComponent extends React.Component<IProps, IState) {
    private list: Array<TestComponent> = [];

    render() {
        let kids: JSX.Element[] = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            list.push(<TestComponent toPrint={ true } ref={ (t) => this.list.push(t) } />);
        }

        return <h1>Main Component</h1>{ list };
    }
}
```